# Ext JS SORTING (2, 5, 30, 100) compare function

Tags: javascript, web, extjs

Using ExtJS 4.2.3. I have list of values which sorts as string and it looks like:

```
   DATA1 (NOW)  | DATA1 (SHOULD BE) |  
  -----------------------------------
       100      |         2         |  
       2        |         5         | 
       30       |         30        | 
       5        |         100       |
```

Exanple of code on ExtJS:

```
 DATA1_store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
                model: DATA1.id,
                proxy: {
                    url: proxyCfg.url,
                    type: proxyCfg.type,
                    reader: {
                        type: "json",
                        root: "data"
                    }
                },
                remoteSort: true,
                sorters: [{
                    property: "data1",
                    direction: "ASC"
                }],
```

Here should work compare function like on javascript:

```
points.sort(function(a, b){return a - b})
```

Asking for help with compare function or mb another way for code part above of ext JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is specify [Ext.data.Field.type](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type) of `data1` field in your model (`'int'` in your case, `'string'` is used by default), like this:

```
fields: [{
    name: 'data1',
    type: 'int'
}]
```

Here is [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2a3e) to illustrate.

Also, you can check [`Ext.data.Field.sortType`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-sortType).

**UPDATE**

If you have to compare values like '1.1.2' and '1.5' I think you can use `Ext.data.Field.sortType`, like this (I do not know the exact data format, so for an example I assume that each part after the point is equal to a number from 0 to 99, and the number of parts is unknown):

```
sortType: function (value) {
    var parts = value.split('.'),
        comparableValue = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
        comparableValue += parts[i] * Math.pow(10, i * -2);
    }
    return comparableValue;
}
```

Here is [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2a43) to illustrate.

Comment: Thx, it's a good answer and I marked it as solved. But on my real data it doesn't work.  Datatype of field in real data is nvarchar. And some of values looks like 1.1.2 or 10.5 and etc. May I ask you to give some advices or code example for this correction?

Comment: @Dmitry, I think you can pass custom function to `sortType` and convert your values to comparable value. Try it. If any problems occur - ask and Ill try to help.

Comment: @Dmitry, I have updated my answer with example, check it.

Comment: Thank you so much, for good examples. I got the logic, but unfortunately, I failed to modify and reproduce for real data. I created new question with a more detailed description [link_stackoverflow_47563820](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563820/ext-js-sorttype-treecolumn).
If it possible, please take a look of it.