# Ext JS SortType treecolumn

Tags: javascript, web, extjs

Using ExtJS 4.2.3. Have form with treecolumn xtype field which contains string value with number in begin. Column has 3 lvls of structure. On first lvl sort needs to be in order like (2, 3, 5, 40, 100 and etc).

[image]

After picking third lvl value in selection form, value in box will look like:

```
3.ABC.<BR>3.23.ABCCDD.<BR>3.23.5.  ABCC
```

Sample of code:

```
enter Picker = new Project.Picker({
                                    title: "Title1",
                                    proxyCfg: {
                                        url: Ext.state.Manager.get("url") + "TreeList",
                                        type: "ajax"},
                                    idProperty: "id",
                                    defaultRootId: "NULL",
                                    nodeParam: "parent_Code",
                                    PickerCfg: [
                                        { name: "id", type: "string", isSC: false },
                                        { xtype: "treecolumn", name: "Fieldname", header: "Header1", type: "string", isSC: true, isHC: true },
                                        { name: "name2", type: "string" },
                                        { name: "code", header: "Header3", type: "string", isSC: true}],
                                    viewConfig: {
                                        listeners: {
                                            itemdblclick: function (view, record) {
                                                Order_Form.getComponent("Grid").selModel.getSelection()[0].set("id", record.get("id"));
                                                Order_Form.getComponent("Grid").selModel.getSelection()[0].set("Fieldname", record.get("Fieldname"));
                                                Order_Form.getComponent("Grid").selModel.getSelection()[0].set("code", record.get("code"));
                                                trigger.setValue(record.get("name2"));
                                                this.up().up().destroy();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    sorters: [{
                                        property: "code",
                                        direction: "ASC"
                                    }]
                                }).show(this, function () { this.getComponent(0).DMS_search(); Picker.getComponent(0).getView().refresh(); });
                            }
                        },
                        tpl: "<table class='Gridd' style='border-collapse: collapse; border: medium none;'><tr><td><b>[Header1]: </b></td><td style='width:100%;'>{Name2}</td></tr><tr><td><b>[Header3]: </b></td><td>{code}</td></tr></table>"
```

Asking for help with sorting in selection form.

Comment: As I understand `Project.Picker` is custom class and it work with `Ext.data.TreeStore` internally. Can you share `Project.Picker` code, please? Better yet, prepare the fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor

Comment: @Sergey Thank you for responding. Added code to [fiddlle.sencha.com](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ach)

Comment: As I can see you use `PickerCfg` as `Ext.data.TreeModel.fields` value. Did you try to specify `sortType` there? I think it should work.

Comment: @Sergey If I understand you correctly I need to specify `sortType` in this code section: `PickerCfg: [
                                        { name: "id", type: "string", isSC: false },
                                        { xtype: "treecolumn", name: "Fieldname", header: "Header1", type: "string", isSC: true, isHC: true },
                                        { name: "name2", type: "string" },
                                        { name: "code", header: "Header3", type: "string", isSC: true}],`.

Comment: @Sergey But I already tried to specify SortType here on Code value `{ name: "code", header: "Header3", type: "string", isSC: true}`, because I use this field as properity for sorters `sorters: [{
                                        property: "code",
                                        direction: "ASC"`. Or I did wrong?

Comment: You understand me correctly. What exactly goes wrong when you add `sortType` to your Project.Picker? It doesnt affect sorting al all? Can you make working fiddle with test data set, please?